# Zend GData set public a video uploaded private

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

with this snippet I'd like to set public a video
uploaded as private

```
$ytConfigData = App_SiteSettings::get('yt');
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($ytConfigData->user,$ytConfigData->password, 'youtube');
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient,
                                 $ytConfigData->gdataAppId,//$applicationId,
                                 $ytConfigData->channel,//$clientId,
                                 $ytConfigData->devkey);
$videoEntry = $yt->getFullVideoEntry('UrI_TxBCME4');
// Set public
$videoEntry->setVideoPublic();
```

but it doesn't work (the video is still private)

Do you know, why ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: $putUrl = $videoEntry->getEditLink()->getHref();
$r = $videoEntry->setVideoPublic();
$yt->updateEntry($videoEntry, $putUrl); It works thanks the same

Comment: Add it as an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

did you try checking your Channel Settings in youtube. You should change the default video privacy settings as well.